# Best way to create, search and modify (key ,value1, value2) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, set, storing-data

My program is searching a log, and counting the number of times some events occur (along with the bytes associated with each event). I would like to store events of interest to me as a (key, value1, value2) where the string is the key, and the values are two longs. I need to be able to search if the key alrady exists in the structure, and I will need to be able to modify the two long values.

I am not going to go the database route or storing the data in another text file.

I was not successful in finding something using the Stack Overflow search, and the Oracle tutorials and collections documentation did little to help me. My options (as I understand it) are:

1. a map consisting of (string, array)
2. 2D array (where I molest strings to longs and back)
3. a tuple object

Am I overlooking other possible solutions that are superior? And if not, which do you suggest I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see why a hash map wouldn't simply do the job. It doesn't seem that complicated

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew the oracle docs state that "each key can map to at most one value", and I need a key to map to two values. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html . I think a map with a string key and a Tuple is the way to go (Aaron Davis's answer).

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by a simple hashmap. Storing a tuple of values or storing a value isn't much different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what you mean by "best" but this is what I'd do. I'd have a map with a string key and a value that is a simple tuple object. You "might" be able to get better performance manually but using a collections implementation of a map is the easiest to use and, more importantly, the easiest for others to understand who might need to read/maintain it later. Also, beware of premature optimization. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A similar, if equally objectionable, option to #2 is to use a 128-bit  `BigInteger`. A much better option, though still a bit hacky, would be to use a [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), which makes it easy to access the higher and lower long values:

```
// set
map.put(key, new UUID(value1, value2);
// get
value1 = map.get(key).getMostSignificantBits();
```

The most "proper" solution would generally be to create a custom class to convey what the values represent and how they're related. If they don't have a relationship and they just share a common key, it may be worth keeping a separate map for each set of values.